# Prove or disprove that if X is homeomorphic to Y in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus Y$

Tags: general-topology

Intuitively if I imagine homeomorphisms to be continuously transforming from one set to the other, it feels like it is true. However, I'm struggling to find an explicit homeomorphism f.

Comment: It’s overkill and there’s likely an elementary answer, but here’s an example where it’s false: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere

Comment: My example in this works for this too: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3916715/can-we-prove-%e2%84%9dn-%e2%88%96-textstraight-line-and-%e2%84%9dn-%e2%88%96-text-an-axis-hom/3916733#3916733

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's true.  The whole $\Bbb R^n$ is homeomorphic to a ball.  But the complement of a ball is not homeomorphic to the empty set.

Answer (score 3):

$\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ is homeomorphic to $\{x\in\Bbb R^n\,:\, \lVert x\rVert>1\}$, but a closed ball is not homeomorphic to a point.

Comment: that's an example of why the *reverse* does not hold.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma It's a counterexample with $X=\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ and $Y=\{x\in\Bbb R^n\,:\, \lVert x\rVert>1\}$ (of course, if the second instance of $\Bbb R^n\setminus X$ in the title is substituted with $\Bbb R^n\setminus Y$).

Comment: Ah, I see. That works.

Answer (score 0):

Knots.  They're all homeomorphic to a circle.  But they are commonly studied by putting tubular neighborhoods around them and studying their complements in $S^3\cong\Bbb R^3\cup\{\infty\}$ (the so-called "knot complement").

Thus all that remains is to convince ourselves that tubular neighborhoods of "different" knots are homeomorphic.  They are all homeomorphic to a torus.

There are also higher dimensional knots.